# alternatives to "Having"

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I have a `SELECT` statement that counts the number of instances and then saves in a variable. It has  a `HAVING` clause that does a `SUM` and a `COUNT`. However since you have to have a `GROUP BY` in order to use *having*, the *select* statement returns 4 lines that are 1 instead of the total being 4. This then doesn't save the *count* into the variable as 4 but as 1 which obviously is not what I need so I am looking for an alternative work around.

```
    select count(distinct p1.community) 
        from
            "Database".prospect p1
    where 
        p1.visit_date >= '2013-07-01' 
        and p1.visit_date <= '2013-09-30'
        and p1.division = '61'  
    group By 
        p1.community
    having 
        sum(p1.status_1) / count(p1.control_code) >= .16;
```

Comment: No group by needed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e77778/1

Comment: Isn't Group By a requirement of having clause?

Comment: Ah, I thought you use MySQL. Not sure about the situation with your DB system.

Comment: `HAVING` has no meaning without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Ok so is there a way that I can do my arithmetic and get rid of the having clause?

Comment: Do you want to perform the check on individual rows?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to see if each community achieves a standard set by our company, where their SUM(status_1) column / count(control_code column) > .16. however i just want to select the count of how many communities achieved this.

Comment: check this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207154/alternative-to-having-and-group-by

Answer (score 2):

This is a reasonable alternative:

```
select count(*)
from (
select p1.community , sum(p1.status_1) / count(p1.control_code) SomeColumn
        from
            "Database".prospect p1
    where 
        p1.visit_date >= '2013-07-01' 
        and p1.visit_date <= '2013-09-30'
        and p1.division = '61'  
    Group By 
        p1.community
) A
where A.SomeColumn >= .16;
```

Comment: I am in pervasive, will this still work here? I can't get it to run